# Consuming OData Servie using DataJS

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code in MVC view i try to call OData Service using Datajs :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var temp = OData.read("http://odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/Genres", function (data,  response) {
     var x = 3;

      });
});
```

i have a break-point on `var x = 3;` but unfortunately the break-point was never hit!  if i put break-point on `OData.Read` i can see its calling the OData-Service but then the callback function never get fired , i dont know what im doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think a breakpoint there is ever hit -- because you are hanging an anonymous function on another function. So the anonymous function will get executed but it is not linked to that place in the source code... If you'd use a named function instead, you could put a breakpoint there. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: i also have an alert there it doesnt show up a message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before calling `OData.Read()`:

```
OData.defaultHttpClient.enableJsonpCallback = true;
```

Also your request doesn't specify format. Change the request string to: *http://odata.netflix.com/v1/Catalog/Genres?$format=json&$callback=?callbackHere*

Comment: still nothing , i think this should be true by default any way

Comment: @Stacker By default the format it is returning is XML. Change it to JSON, I have updated the answer.